# How to remove a nested categories in Joomla from a PHP script

Tags: php, joomla

I would like to develop my application for better functionality. I need to remove a category of articles using a PHP script in Joomla. e.g. I have a main category and subcategory. How can I remove selected subcategory and then run rebuild? Instead using Joomla administrator I would like using own script.

I use folowing sample code to create new subcategory:

```
<?php

   define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
   define('JPATH_BASE', '../');
   define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );

   require_once ( JPATH_BASE . 'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
   require_once ( JPATH_BASE . 'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );
   require_once ( JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR .DS. 'components'.DS.'com_categories'.DS.'models'.DS.'category.php');

   $mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
   $mainframe->initialise();

   $extension = 'com_content';
   $title     = 'nowa';
   $parent_id = 9;

// JTableCategory is autoloaded in J! 3.0, so...
if (version_compare(JVERSION, '3.0', 'lt'))
{
   JTable::addIncludePath(JPATH_PLATFORM . 'joomla/database/table');
}

// Initialize a new category
$category = JTable::getInstance('Category');
$category->extension = $extension;
$category->title = $title;
$category->published = 1;
$category->access = 1;
$category->params = '{"category_layout":"","image":""}';
$category->metadata = '{"author":"","robots":""}';
$category->language = '*';

// Set the location in the tree
$category->setLocation($parent_id, 'last-child');

// Check to make sure our data is valid
if (!$category->check())
{
   JError::raiseNotice(500, $category->getError());
   return false;
}

// Now store the category
if (!$category->store(true))
{
   JError::raiseNotice(500, $category->getError());
   return false;
}

// Build the path for our category
$category->rebuildPath($category->id);
```

When I run this code, I receive new subcategory with assets table.
In the same way I would like remove any category.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, have you considered asking the question on http://joomla.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: I tried with getInstance('Category); and then $table->delete($id); but it's not works. I did not know this site.

Comment: I updated my question.